# How to set up per-seat subscription with Stripe?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments, firebase-extensions

Good day!

I am trying build a per-seat subscription model for my web site.
Before, I tried use Checkout session to provide "place", to write personal data, but the max what I reached - is creating default Subscription that you could cancel for instance.

**What I wanna do?**

• Figure out, if possible, how to create per-seat subscription through Checkout session and after, on event *"User joined"* automatically replace new price of the subscription.

• If through Checkout session that is not possible, how to implement it through code?
How to get a user's card and how to upgrade later the subscription.

I read [the article on Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#advanced), but from that I can't figure how I get client data as card.

In addition, I use Stripe Extension on firebase with cloud functions.

Hope, this problem will be solved :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a per-seat type subscription with Stripe Checkout. For that, you need to have a recurring price, just as [the article suggests](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#model-flat-rate-per-seat-on-stripe). Then pass the price into `line_items` property when creating a subscription, along with the initial quantity. For example, a customer might want to purchase 5 seats/licenses right away. You can also enable [adjustable_quantity](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=curl#create_checkout_session-line_items-adjustable_quantity) setting to allow the user to change the quantity on the Checkout Session page.

When a new user joins, use the [Update Subscription API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update) to change the [quantity](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-items-quantity) of the item. For example, if the new total number of users you are serving is 11, set the quantity of the price to 11. More info [here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/quantities).

If you don’t want to use Stripe Checkout, you can create a subscription via API, by following [this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/build-subscriptions?ui=elements). The upgrade step looks the same as in the other solution.

Besides that, Stripe has a [Billing Customer Portal](https://stripe.com/blog/billing-customer-portal) that allows users to modify their subscriptions, it’s worth taking a look.

Comment: Okay, how I can get subscription id after succeed in Stripe Checkout?

Comment: Hi! I have already successfully updated subscription, but I have weak place, I don't save subscription Id, and if for some reason user will have more than 1 subscription, my program will just see the new one one, so ideally, I should find how to save the data and how can I after update necessary one.

Comment: You can listen to “checkout.session.completed” webhook event, which contains a [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions) object, it has a `subscription` [property](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-subscription) on it. Alternatively, you can [get the Checkout Session by its ID](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/retrieve) to find the `subscription` property.